How to make span's content box size equal to its parent's?
I need the size of span1's content box be equal to the size of span2's content box - So that I can move the red marker along the page WITHOUT HAVING TO CHANGE THE width and height OVER AGAIN EVERY SINGLE TIME I'LL NEED MARKERS.
NOTE THAT THE RED MARKER WILL BE DISPLAYED ON A SCREENSHOT - AND NOT A PARAGRAPH AS IN THE CODE BELLOW.
I tried to change it to position: relative and also display: inline-block but these make it impossible for the red marker span to display correctly.
I used text with transparent color so that I can fill the block with letters and it will grow accordingly without showing them.
Should I have put span2 (red marker), inside span2?
Any other proposal?
Thank you very much!
(YOU NEED TO OPEN IT IN A FULL WINDOW TO SEE THE RED MARKER)


.panel-one {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
}

.m-aquamarine {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.m-red {
  position: absolute;

  right: 720px;

  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.3;

  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" ; href="COPY.css">

  <title>Copy</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="panel-one">
      <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/jralaTFd.png" width="100%">

      <p>
        <span class="m-aquamarine">

          Hey Gustaf! Azng sjczv zncsn djfandz czns!!

        </span>

        <span class="m-red">fdfsdfsdfshdghdgnsdfsdfsfsd</span>
      
        Dzns kds fdskcznc eandz ncz!?!</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>




I think the quickest solution is to just put span2 into span1 as a child element, then have its width be 100%, although it is not very clear what the end goal is...

Could you please re-clarify what you're working with? Sounds like you are trying to overlay markers on images that contains text. While I'm not sure how to do so, using text to grow the span works only if you can guarantee the span to have exact font size/line-height/line-wrap of the screenshot. Do you have the coordinate and length of each sentence you want to highlight already?

Yes, it almost works - But the  (span2) still isn't part of span1, if I inspect them on Chrome then it shows each of them is having its own content box.. Is there an alternative for ? Maybe  or something else? Thank you @VanjaStojanović

Yes I do have, thank you for helping me @SyndRain
